# How to generate all permutations of 1 and 0 bits of a given size in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, collections, combinatorics

I would like to be able to generate an array of all possible permutations of a `Bool` (`true/false` or `1/0`) of a given size `n`, in Swift.  For example, given `n=2` the result of calling `generate(2)` would be

```
let array: [Bool] = generate(2) // [[false, false], [false, true], [true, false], [true, true]]
```

I looked in Swift-algorithms but all I see is permutations and combinations of a provided array of elements.  These algorithms don't appear to address scenario for a `Bool` with `n>2`.  Also, I'm not sure what name to call this algorithm.

Comment: It's just every number from 0 to 2^N - 1. If N is not to big you can just use `for let i = 0..<pow(2, N)`

Comment: I don't know swift, so I can't help you there, but permutation and combination both refer to reordering/drawing of an existing array, i.e. it wouldn't *generate* [ 00, 01, 10, 11 ], but rather would take that as input and generate { [00, 01, 10, 11], [00, 01, 11, 10], [00, 10, 01, 11], [00, 10, 11, 01], etc}. So searching for those terms won't lead you to the right places.  You might try "generate complete binary tree of depth N" or something like that, since a traversal of such a tree's indices would yield the set you want. (For the general case. As Cy says, plain binary numbers are easier.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun a functional approach:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection {
    var combinations: [Self] { generate(2) }
    func generate(_ n: Int) -> [Self] {
        repeatElement(self, count: n).reduce([.init()]) { result, element in
            result.flatMap { elements in
                element.map { elements + CollectionOfOne($0) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let elements = [false, true]  // [false, true]
let combinations = elements.combinations  // [[false, false], [false, true], [true, false], [true, true]]
let generateThree = elements.generate(3)  // [[false, false, false], [false, false, true], [false, true, false], [false, true, true], [true, false, false], [true, false, true], [true, true, false], [true, true, true]]
```

or

```
let elements = [0, 1]  // [0, 1]
let combinations = elements.combinations  // [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
let generateThree = elements.generate(3)  // [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

or with Strings (Collection Of Characters):

```
let elements = "01" // "01"
let combinations = elements.combinations  // ["00", "01", "10", "11"]
let generateThree = elements.generate(3)  // ["000", "001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple recursive implementation:

```swift
import Foundation

func recursion(depth: Int, arr: [[Bool]]) -> [[Bool]] {
  if depth == .zero {
    return arr
  }
  var newArr: [[Bool]] = []
  for item in arr {
    let newItem1 = item + [false]
    let newItem2 = item + [true]
    newArr += [newItem1, newItem2]
  }
  return recursion(depth: depth-1, arr: newArr)
}

print(recursion(depth: 1, arr: [[]]))
print(recursion(depth: 2, arr: [[]]))
print(recursion(depth: 3, arr: [[]]))
```

This gives the output:

```swift
[[false], [true]]
[[false, false], [false, true], [true, false], [true, true]]
[[false, false, false], [false, false, true], [false, true, false], [false, true, true], [true, false, false], [true, false, true], [true, true, false], [true, true, true]]
```